# Convert RGB to RGBA in C

Tags: c, image

I need to copy the contents of a byte array representing an image in RGB byte order into another RGBA(4 bytes per pixel) buffer. The alpha channel will get filled later. What would be the fastest way of achieving this?

Comment: I would expect a for loop, but wait for some better ideas. :)

Comment: I'd recommend Mikola's solution. I hope I am not insulting you by saying this but you're asking a fairly simple question so here's the warning: "_don't forget_ to malloc the space for the destination."

Comment: Also... You're not going to get better speed than by implementing any of the below solutions. Maybe you can make the in-memory work 10-20% faster but don't bother. This task will by 99% I/O so you're wasting your precious human time for a .001% improvement.

Comment: Yeah I'll go with mikola's answer. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 5):

How tricky do you want it?  You could set it up to copy a 4-byte word at a time, which might be a bit faster on some 32-bit systems:

```
void fast_unpack(char* rgba, const char* rgb, const int count) {
    if(count==0)
        return;
    for(int i=count; --i; rgba+=4, rgb+=3) {
        *(uint32_t*)(void*)rgba = *(const uint32_t*)(const void*)rgb;
    }
    for(int j=0; j<3; ++j) {
        rgba[j] = rgb[j];
    }
}
```

The extra case on the end is to deal with the fact that the rgb array is missing a byte.  You could also make it a bit faster using aligned moves and SSE instructions, working in multiples of 4 pixels at a time.  If you're feeling really ambitious, you can try even more horribly obfuscated things like prefetching a cache line into the FP registers, for example, then blitting it across to the other image all at once.  Of course the mileage you get out of these optimizations is going to be highly dependent on the specific system configuration you are targetting, and I would be really skeptical that there is much benefit at all to doing any of this instead of the simple thing.

And my simple experiments confirm that this is indeed a *little* bit faster, at least on my x86 machine.  Here is a benchmark:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <time.h>

void fast_unpack(char* rgba, const char* rgb, const int count) {
    if(count==0)
        return;
    for(int i=count; --i; rgba+=4, rgb+=3) {
        *(uint32_t*)(void*)rgba = *(const uint32_t*)(const void*)rgb;
    }
    for(int j=0; j<3; ++j) {
        rgba[j] = rgb[j];
    }
}

void simple_unpack(char* rgba, const char* rgb, const int count) {
    for(int i=0; i<count; ++i) {
        for(int j=0; j<3; ++j) {
            rgba[j] = rgb[j];
        }
        rgba += 4;
        rgb  += 3;
    }
}

int main() {
    const int count = 512*512;
    const int N = 10000;

    char* src = (char*)malloc(count * 3);
    char* dst = (char*)malloc(count * 4);

    clock_t c0, c1;    
    double t;
    printf("Image size = %d bytes\n", count);
    printf("Number of iterations = %d\n", N);

    printf("Testing simple unpack....");
    c0 = clock();
    for(int i=0; i<N; ++i) {
        simple_unpack(dst, src, count);
    }
    c1 = clock();
    printf("Done\n");
    t = (double)(c1 - c0) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("Elapsed time: %lf\nAverage time: %lf\n", t, t/N);


    printf("Testing tricky unpack....");
    c0 = clock();
    for(int i=0; i<N; ++i) {
        fast_unpack(dst, src, count);
    }
    c1 = clock();
    printf("Done\n");
    t = (double)(c1 - c0) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("Elapsed time: %lf\nAverage time: %lf\n", t, t/N);

    return 0;
}
```

And here are the results (compiled with g++ -O3):

> Image size = 262144 bytes
>
> Number of iterations = 10000
>
> Testing simple unpack....Done
>
> Elapsed time: 3.830000
>
> Average time: 0.000383
>
> Testing tricky unpack....Done
>
> Elapsed time: 2.390000
>
> Average time: 0.000239

So, maybe about 40% faster on a good day.

Comment: This is platform specific code, because not every hardware supports unaligned integer pointer access.

Comment: @Omri Barel: It's true the optimization is platform specific, and note that I did say *some* 32-bit systems, not all.  But this is still valid C code, and it will work on any standards compliant compiler, regardless of architecture.   Moreover, on x86/64, it works just fine and it is indeed faster than the naive solution (and much easier to maintain than assembly, which isn't even compiler portable).  If do aligned data access (which would be faster and more portable) then things get nasty, and you have to do stuff like process multiple pixels at once and the boundary cases become ugly.

Comment: I've taken your code and added another function to process 12 bytes at a time (reading 3 32-bit values and producing 4 32-bit RGBA values using 5 shifts and 2 ORs). It's faster (because of the unrolling) and has no unaligned access. Still, I'm sure Abrash could do it faster.

Comment: there is my test results from iPad (armv7)
Image size = 262144 bytes
Number of iterations = 100
Testing simple unpack....Done
Elapsed time: 2.126318
Average time: 0.021263
Testing tricky unpack....Done
Elapsed time: 0.646655
Average time: 0.006467
optimized version 3 times faster :)

Answer (score 4):

The fastest was would be to use a library that implements the conversion for you rather than writing it yourself.  Which platform[s] are you targeting?

If you insist on writing it yourself for some reason, write a simple and correct version first.  Use that.  If the performance is inadequate, *then* you can think about optimizing it.  In general, this sort of conversion is best done using vector permutes, but the exact optimal sequence varies depending on the target architecture.

Answer (score 2):

```
struct rgb {
   char r;
   char g;
   char b;
};

struct rgba {
   char r;
   char g;
   char b;
   char a;
}

void convert(struct rgba * dst, const struct rgb * src, size_t num)
{
    size_t i;
    for (i=0; i<num; i++) {
        dst[i].r = src[i].r;
        dst[i].g = src[i].g;
        dst[i].b = src[i].b;
    }
}
```

This would be the cleaner solution, but as you mention an array of bytes, you should use this:

```
// num is still the size in pixels. So dst should have space for 4*num bytes,
// while src is supposed to be of length 3*num.
void convert(char * dst, const char * src, size_t num)
{
    size_t i;
    for (i=0; i<num; i++) {
        dst[4*i] = src[3*i];
        dst[4*i+1] = src[3*i+1];
        dst[4*i+2] = src[3*i+2];
    }
}
```

Comment: The question was about a byte array, not an array of structures.

Comment: @Omri Barel:  The same idea would work trivially.  You could even just do a cast to convert the structure array to the pointer array.  However, some care would be needed to make sure the compiler didn't do anything sneaky with the struct alignment.  For this solution to be correct, there really should be a pragma pack around those structs.

Comment: You are both right - I oversaw the "byte array" part and thus have added another solution.

Comment: @Mikola: if you're going for a non-portable, compiler-dependent solution, why not use assembly? That would certainly be the fastest solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think i remmember a Nehe tutorial of doing something like that, but fast.

Its [here](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/playing_avi_files_in_opengl/23001/)

The interesting part is here:

```
void flipIt(void* buffer)                       // Flips The Red And Blue Bytes (256x256)
{
    void* b = buffer;                       // Pointer To The Buffer
    __asm                               // Assembler Code To Follow
    {
        mov ecx, 256*256                    // Set Up A Counter (Dimensions Of Memory Block)
        mov ebx, b                      // Points ebx To Our Data (b)
        label:                          // Label Used For Looping
            mov al,[ebx+0]                  // Loads Value At ebx Into al
            mov ah,[ebx+2]                  // Loads Value At ebx+2 Into ah
            mov [ebx+2],al                  // Stores Value In al At ebx+2
            mov [ebx+0],ah                  // Stores Value In ah At ebx

            add ebx,3                   // Moves Through The Data By 3 Bytes
            dec ecx                     // Decreases Our Loop Counter
            jnz label                   // If Not Zero Jump Back To Label
    }
}
```

what it does is pretty self explanatory, and it should be easy to transform this into adding the alpha byte.

Comment: That doesn't really do what the OP asked for, which was to unpack a 3-byte RGB array into a a 4-byte RGBA array; rather it just swaps the red/blue bytes in place on an RGB array...  So I guess I am not too sure why it is relevant?

Comment: As I wrote, it would be pretty easy to transform this into adding the alpha byte.

Comment: That's not helpful. Either provide a solution that answers the question posed or just ignore it. If it is so easy to add the alpha byte, do it yourself

Answer (score 0):

Just create array with size of 4/3 of source array. Read entire array and write it to RGBA array, but after every 3bytes insert 255 for alpha.