# How quickly copy data from a RGBA image to RGB image, and back

Tags: c++, image, buffer, rgb, rgba

What is the fastest way in C/C++ to copy data from a buffer representing an image of 4channels (RGBA, 8 bit per channel) to another buffer representing an image of 3channels (RGB, 8 bit per channel too) discarding the alpha channel?. Both images have the same number of pixels, width and height. 
I´m aware of [Convert RGB to RGBA in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7069090/convert-rgb-to-rgba-in-c) , but that is RGB->RGBA.